# Is there a way to increase the upload size of my zip file?

Tags: php, file-upload

Zip files over 65mb won't upload to my database and file folder. The server allows 500MB and php allows 128MB

I have up the size of the file to determine how large the file can be before it stops working.

This is the form

Enter Your Account Email: 
 
          Upload File:
           
          upload

And this is the code to add the files. It works but stops at a certain size.

```
 if (!in_array($extension, ['mp3', 'wma', 'wav', 'zip'])) {
    echo "Your file extension must be .mov, .wmv, .mp4 or .zip";
} elseif ($_FILES['myfile']['size'] > 100000000) { // file shouldn't be larger than 1Gigabyte
    echo "File too large!";
```

To upload zip files at least 125MB

Comment: can you change it in php.ini?

Comment: I"m trying that now.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Answer (score 0):

first create `.htaccess` file and copy paste it in `.htaccess` file in your root directory.

When you make change on php configration through `.htaccess` you should put configrations in  `IfModule tag,`.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
   php_value post_max_size 100M
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Like this 

file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 5000M
post_max_size = 5000M

Yet still doesn't work

Comment: Nope it still did not go through at (96,845,006 bytes (96.8 MB on disk)) I don't know why it is not working. The php.ini is in the main folder should it be in the folder the php file is in, but in that case I would need more than one php.ini file.

Comment: I have tried this in the .htacess files and nothing

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
   php_value post_max_size 100M
</IfModule>